# How to get the custom post type id

Tags: wordpress, slider, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, slick.js

I have a product page which is a custom post type, now i want the category id of that specific page and place it in the post loop. And create a slick slider with it.

this is what i came up with.

single-product page

```
<section class="product">
    <div class="productslider">
        <?php
        global $post;
        $Taxonomy = get_object_taxonomies('producten');

        if (count($Taxonomy) > 0) {
            foreach ($Taxonomy as $tax) {
                $args = array(
                    'taxonomy' => $tax,
                );

                $cats = get_categories($args);

                $cats = $cats[0]->term_id;
            }
        }

        $args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'post_type' => 'producten', 'category' =>  $cats);

        $posts = get_posts($args);
        if ($posts) :
            foreach ($posts as $post) :
                setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <div class="productslider__slide">
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                </div>

            <?php endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif; ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

slick

```
$('.productslider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    arrows: false,
    dots: true,
    centerMode: true,
});
```

is this a good solution?
it seems like i am getting the same ids on every page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it shows you the same ids, as you are getting the same Id's from the loop,

here is your code

`$cats = $cats[0]->term_id;`

above line only gets the first ID from the loop, and you are using this category id on the `get_posts()` that's why you will get the same id's every time.

try modifying this code:

```
$cat_array   = array();
$cats        = get_categories($args);        
$cat_array[] = $cats->term_id;

$args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'post_type' => 'producten', 'category' =>  $cat_array);
```

Hope it will help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

How i solved it using Manan Vyas answer

```
$Taxonomy = get_object_taxonomies('producten');
   if (count($Taxonomy) > 0) {
      foreach ($Taxonomy as $tax) {
         $args = array(
            'taxonomy' => $tax,
         );

         $cat_array = array();
         $cats = get_categories($args);  

         foreach($cats as $data) {
            array_push($cat_array, $data->term_id);
         }
      }
   }

$args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'post_type' => 'producten', 'category' =>  $cat_array);
```

Comment: You asked how to get the category id and manan told you how to do it. You should accept his post as the answer to your question. He took the time and helped you out. Would be better to edit your post and add the corrected code if you want to share the whole thing.